# I can't export in QGIS a Shapefile to PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

When I try export a pipe network shape to PostGIS I get this error:

```
Problema inserindo feições do arquivo:
C:/PP/gvSIG_Projects/Shapes/Abastecimento/QGIS_VATROCOADUTOR.shp

Ocorreu um erro no banco de dados ao executar este SQL:
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('public','QGIS_VATROCOADUTOR','the_geom',-1,'NULL',2)
O erro foi:
ERROR:  Invalid type name "NULL(2)" - valid ones are:
    POINT, MULTIPOINT,
    LINESTRING, MULTILINESTRING,
    POLYGON, MULTIPOLYGON,
    CIRCULARSTRING, COMPOUNDCURVE, MULTICURVE,
    CURVEPOLYGON, MULTISURFACE,
    GEOMETRY, GEOMETRYCOLLECTION,
    POINTM, MULTIPOINTM,
    LINESTRINGM, MULTILINESTRINGM,
    POLYGONM, MULTIPOLYGONM,
    CIRCULARSTRINGM, COMPOUNDCURVEM, MULTICURVEM
    CURVEPOLYGONM, MULTISURFACEM, TRIANGLE, TRIANGLEM,
    POLYHEDRALSURFACE, POLYHEDRALSURFACEM, TIN, TINM
    or GEOMETRYCOLLECTIONM
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT AddGeometryColumn('',$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7)"
PL/pgSQL function addgeometrycolumn(character varying,character varying,character varying,integer,character varying,integer,boolean) line 5 at SQL statement
```

I can't interpret this error can you help me?

Comment: How was the shapefile created? How are you trying to import it (which tool)?

Comment: Whichever method you are using for the import, I think an important clue is where the error states:  `Invalid type name, Null(2)`.  You need to actually specify which geometry type you are importing.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the function definition at http://postgis.net/docs/AddGeometryColumn.html

you see that the parametres should be

- schema_name
- table_name
- column_name
- SRID
- type
- dimension
- use_typmod=true

Your function call does not state a correct value for type (point, line, polygon), and I wonder if SRID=-1 is intended.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I has used spittool in Qgis to try the export. I was trying export lines but in the tool I don't see any option to choose that.

Comment: Maybe the same problem as here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29128/error-when-importing-shapefile-to-postgis-database. Have you tried simple copy and pasting all elements of the shapefile and inserting in an existing postgis layer?

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem, I have imported from pgAdminPlugin, and in options I change UTF-8 to LATIN1, and everything worked ok.

Thanks for you help,
Paulo Praça